# SRU-12VDC-SD-C vs SRD-12VDC-SL-C

Tags: relay, datasheet, substitution

I'm following this guide [1] to made a Z-Wave compatible doorbell and it requires a SRU-12VDC-SD-C relay.  I know nothing really of electronics and have found a SRD-12VDC-SL-C relay on Amazon [2] which looks to be similar, but because I've little knowledge I don't know for sure.  Will the SRD-12VDC-SL-C work for the use I intend?

**EDIT** 
I've looked up the datasheets [3], [4] and they don't really mean anything to me.

**Links**

1, http://www.robbshop.nl/about-z-wave/z-wave-projects/z-wave-doorbel - this link is half in english, it's enough to understand what's going on.  You will have to select the UK language selection drop down in the top left of the page for this link to work

2, http://www.amazon.co.uk/2pcs-Power-Relay-SRD-12VDC-SL-C-Type/dp/B00MO75O30/

3, https://www.ghielectronics.com/downloads/man/20084141716341001RelayX1.pdf

4, http://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=SRU_series_relay_data_sheet_E&DocType=DS&DocLang=EN

Comment: The first link is trashed and also not in English.

Comment: If you Google those two part numbers and search through their image pages, you'll find their photos and data sheets, including dimensions, pinouts, and coil and contact data.

Comment: "Oops, er is iets fout gegaan" now this don't sound like a freaking working page to me.

Comment: Does that mean that this relay will work with 12V DC impulse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between the SD version and the SL version is the power consumption of the coil. [image]

I don't see a reason why you could not use this one.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.